# Python CSV Module (.cell)

Tags: python, sql, csv, cell, openpyxl

I want to sort (to make a table) my data's from a csv-file. Now I have a template with the same thing I want to make, but with the openpyxl-library instead of the csv-library, which I use. In the openpyxl-library you can use ".cell" to speak to only to one cell. How can I do this with csv?
[Example with openpyxl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TDsd.png)

This is my current code for csv (file is the variable for my file, and .cell doesn't works):

```
csvreader = csv.reader(file)

column = []
column = next(csvreader)
for x in range(1, csvreader.line_num+1):
name = csvreader.delimiter(1, x).value
sqltype = ("INTEGER" if type(csvreader.delimiter(2, x).value) == int else "NVARCHAR(255)")
print(f'"{name}" {sqltype},')
```

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Please include your code and ask questions about it.

Comment: Also, don't post images of code, error, otput, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text.

Comment: The reader returns a tuple for each row. You can access individual elements via their position. Ie. for row in csvreader: cell = row[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no cells in CSV so what you can do is loop through the file line by line.

so your code will look like:

1. for loop going line by line,
2. for each line split it by commas

for 2. now you have an array that has each value of the CSV, and the "cell" will be the array value so splitterLine[5] would be cell 6.

if you include the code any code that you started I could help you out more.

Comment: You can see my code for csv in the question above. 
File is the variable for my file, this should work, but obviously the csvreader.cell statement doesn't work.

Comment: awesome glad you got it figured out

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved:
It's really simple, because with the CSV-Library you easily can make a Array with a csv-list.
The Solution:

```
columns = []
for x in range(0, 10+1):
name = header[x]
sqltype = ("INTEGER" if type(header[x]) == int else "NVARCHAR(255)")
print(f'"{name}" {sqltype},')
columns.append(name)
```

How to make an array:

```
header = []
header = next(csvreader)
header
```

Variable csvreader(file is the variable from my imported file):

```
csvreader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
```

Comment: The documentation of the CSV module in the standard library covers this and more clearly, too.